# schedule task alfresco administrator

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm not really familiar to alfresco, so I wish that the question will not bother everyone. However I hope for your help.
When I create a trial user for alfresco by webscript, but I want the user will be delete after 30 days trial. How can I do that? Can anyone give me an idea? (I hope that I will not have to use java-backend webscript  because I never do it before.)
Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scheduled custom action triggered every day that checks if some user has been created more than 30 days ago. For the custom action you should see my blog, or just google it, you'll find a lot of material about.
If you need some help with the javascript action that is triggered, just let us know.

Comment: Thank you very much Alch3mi5t, I have read your blog. I will try it now. By the way, I want to use reCaptcha of Google in alfresco page by webscript. I wonder if you know how to solve it?